# Display period in a 2D Grid Maze in a for loop

Tags: c++

I have a BFS algorithm that finds the shortest path in a maze. I need to output the shortest path in the maze with periods. I have the maze set up with spaces and walls. Wall is char 254. My problem is I cannot figure out how to display periods from the path since my maze is a different size than my path vector. Does anybody know how to display periods for the path? The display function I am talking about is the display function not the displayMaze function. Here is the code:

```
#include "Grid.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include "conio.h"

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int sx, sy, tx, ty;
    while(1)
    {
        Grid g;
        g.displayMaze();
        cout << "Enter start row: ";
        cin >> sx;
        if (sx == -1)break;
        cout << "Enter start column: ";
        cin >> sy;
        cout << "Enter target row: ";
        cin >> tx;
        cout << "Enter target column: ";
        cin >> ty;
        g.bfs(sx, sy, tx, ty);
        g.display();
        cout << "Press any key to go again:\n\n\n";
        getch();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Grid header

```
#ifndef GRID_H
#define GRID_H

struct Node
{
    bool isWall = false;
    bool isVisited = false;
    Node * parent = nullptr;
    vector<Node*> cn;
};
class Grid {
public:
    static const int SIZE = 20;
    Node * maze[SIZE][SIZE];
    Node * start = nullptr;
    Node * target = nullptr;
    vector<Node*> path;
    string mazeFile =
            "x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x "
            "x o o o x o x o o o o o o o x o x o o x "
            "x x x o o o x x x o x x x o o o x o o x "
            "x o x o x o o o x o o o x o x o o o x x "
            "x o o o x x x o o o x o o o x x x o o x "
            "x o x x x o x x x o o o x x x o x x x x "
            "x o o x x o x x x x x o o o x o x o o x "
            "x o o x x o x x x x x o o o o o o o o x "
            "x x o x x o o o o o x x o x x o o o o x "
            "x o o o o o x o x o o o o o o o x o x x "
            "x x o o x o x x x x x x o o x o x o x x "
            "x o o o x o x o o o o x o o x o x o o x "
            "x x x o o o x x x o x x x o o o x x x x "
            "x o x o x o o o x o x o x o x o o o x x "
            "x o o o x x x o o o x o x o x x x o o x "
            "x o x x x o x x x o o o x o x o x x x x "
            "x o o o x o x o o o x o o o x o x o o x "
            "x o o o o o o o o x x o o o o o o o o x "
            "x o o x x o o o o x x x o x x o o o o x "
            "x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x "
            ;
    Grid();
    void displayMaze();
    void display();
    void bfs(int startRow, int startCol, int targetRow, int targetCol);
    Grid(const Grid& orig);
    virtual ~Grid();
private:

};

#endif /* GRID_H */
```

Grid Source

```
#include "Grid.h"

Grid::Grid() {
    stringstream ss(mazeFile, ios::in);
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            char buffer;
            Node * n = new Node();
            ss >> buffer;
            if(buffer == 'x')
            {
                n->isWall = true;
            }
            maze[i][j] = n;
        }
    }
    
    //connect the nodes
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            if ((i - 1) >= 0)
            {
                maze[i][j]->cn.push_back(maze[i-1][j]);
            }
            if ((i + 1) <= SIZE -1)
            {
                maze[i][j]->cn.push_back(maze[i+1][j]);
            }
             if ((j - 1) >= 0)
            {
                maze[i][j]->cn.push_back(maze[i][j - 1]);
            }
            if ((j + 1) <= SIZE -1)
            {
                maze[i][j]->cn.push_back(maze[i][j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
void Grid::displayMaze()
{
    cout << "\t0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0\n";
     for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
         cout << i+1 << "\t";
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            if(maze[i][j]->isWall)
            {
                cout << char(254) << " ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "  ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
     }
}
void Grid::bfs(int startRow, int startCol, int targetRow, int targetCol)
{
    start = maze[startRow][startCol];
    start->isWall = maze[startRow][startCol]->isWall;
    target = maze[targetRow][targetCol];
    if(start->isWall == true)
    {
        cout << "Start is a wall" << endl;
        return;
    }
    if(target->isWall == true)
    {
        cout << "Target is wall" << endl;
        return;
    }
    Node * current = start;
    int m = current->cn.size();
    queue<Node *> myQueue;
    myQueue.push(current);
    while(!myQueue.empty())
    {
        current = myQueue.front();
        if(current == target)
        {
            break;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < current->cn.size(); i++)
        {
            if(current->cn[i]->isVisited == false)
            {
            myQueue.push(current->cn[i]);
            current->cn[i]->isVisited = true;
            current->cn[i]->parent = current;
            }
            if (current->cn[i] == target)
            {
              break;
            }
        }
        myQueue.pop();
    }
    while(current != start)
            {
            path.push_back(current);
            current = current->parent;
            }
}

void Grid::display()
{
    cout << "\t1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0\n";
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
    cout << i << "\t";
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            if(maze[i][j]->isWall)
            {
                cout << char(254) << " ";
            }
            else if(!maze [i][j]->isWall)
            {
                cout << "  ";
            }
            else if(maze[i][j] == path[i])
            {
                cout << "." << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
     }
}
Grid::Grid(const Grid& orig) {
}

Grid::~Grid() {
}
```

Comment: Instead of `if(maze[i][j] == path[i])` you need a utility function and then something like `if(PointIsOnPath(i, j))`.

Comment: In your path vector, store the POSITION of each point in your maze. With that, you can easily change each char of your maze with the associated point

Comment: Ok can you be more detailed...so I need a seperate function and I just call that function in the for loop in the display function?

Comment: If I store each position in my path vector then the path vector wont be storing the shortest path anymore right?

Comment: Why ?
If you store each position in your path vector, from what I understood, that will change nothing to the shortest path. You'll juste need to make a for loop trhough your path, and change each position given by the path vector in maze by a point

Comment: ok i thought you were saying store all the positions in the maze in my path vector

Answer (score 0):

In your path vector, store the positions of each point. If you have a vector of the positions in your string maze, you just need to change each position, given by your path vector, in your string maze by a point.

It is a simple for loop to apply

Comment: Ok my positions are only in the maze and in my cn vector. Position is not part of my struct so I am unsure of how to add positions to my path vector.

Comment: @johnnyboy1899 Can you describe what is the cn vector ?

Comment: The cn vector holds all the positions connected to a position. So it can contain either 2, 3, or 4 depending on where you are on the matrix. it can never hold more than 4 since a position can only be connected top, bottom, left, right. If you are on outer row it can be either 2 or 3.

Comment: i used it in my bfs to find all the connections to add to my queue

Comment: @johnnyboy1899 You can't add the position in your Node struct ? With that if you have a node, you can get the position from it

Comment: No I dont think I can do that I think I am supposed to use the path vector. I see what your saying though.

Comment: @johnnyboy1899 I think I understood how you can add the position to a vector. In the function `void Grid::bfs` in the for loop, here you can add (or subtract) 1 to startCol, and startRow, according to the value of cn elements of the node (if it get up, you add 1 to startCol etc...) The resulting path can be memorized then.

Comment: i think thats what the cn vector is for...it already gives me all the positions and connections